# Diferencia entre "hacer a pelo y a pluma" y "hacer a pluma y a pelo"

Tags: modismos, españa, locuciones

Curioseando en el Diccionario de la lengua he encontrado que [**hacer a pelo y a pluma**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SPSNBuG) es

> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Ser bisexual

mientras que [**hacer a pluma y a pelo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TQKRqRS) es

> 1. loc. verb. coloq. **hacer a todo.**

y [**hacer a todo** alguien](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Jwhmcap) es

> 1. loc. verb. Estar dispuesto, o ser a propósito, para servir en todo aquello a lo que se quiera aplicar.
> 2. loc. verb. Estar en disposición de recibir algo que le den.

¿Cómo es que el cambio de orden relativo de "pluma" y "pelo" transforma tan radicalmente el significado de la locución?

EDICION

En el Diccionario de Autoridades se recoge **Hacer a pluma y a pelo**:

> Phrase que significa estar dispuesto a admitir y recibir todo lo que se ofrezca, de qualquier especie que sea, con alusion à las aves y à la caza de animales.

Comment: Yo creo que no lo hace. Esta ;a busqué hace tiempo y viene de los cazadores, cuando da igual disparar a pelo (un conejo, ciervo o similar) que a pluma (un pato, perdiz u otro ave). Es un "lo mismo me da que me da lo mismo" y esa locución "hacer a todo" en ocasiones es el eufemismo de "bisexual". Creo que esto es más una inexactitud (o incompletitud) del diccionario. No creo que nadie en el habla coloquial haga realmente esa distinción.

Comment: Le adicioné la etiqueta España porque por aquí por Colombia no usamos esa expresión. Aquí decimos que le gusta "de res y de marrano"

Comment: @nos ...hablaba de la acepción de bisexual.

Answer (score 2):

Coincido con Diego en que puede ser una inexactitud del diccionario. La expresión "hacer a pelo y a pluma" veo que se añadió al diccionario en su edición manual de 1989 ya con la definición de "ser bisexual". Sin embargo, esta entrada en el CORDE no da a entender eso mismo:

> *Porque estos lusitanos hacen a pelo y a pluma. Están con Azaña para derribar la República portuguesa y con Prieto para dar mulé a la República española. Van de pillos a pillos.*
>
> Ricardo León, "Cristo en los infiernos", 1941 (España).

"Dar mulé" era una expresión de la germanía que equivalía a "matar", luego el ejemplo parece que equivale a que les da lo mismo una cosa que otra, que están a todo. De ahí sí que parece que se puede inferir una evolución hacia la acepción de "ser bisexual", que se extrae de expresiones similares como "le da lo mismo carne que pescado", pero no creo que sea aplicable aquí.

O este otro ejemplo:

> *Todo se fue al hoyo de pronto: la guerra nos dejó a todos con las patas colgando. Y eso que fue civil, que si llega a ser militar. Entonces me llamaron la Negocia. Hubo que hacer a pelo y a pluma. Hasta portar alijos de Gibraltar, que no sé por qué ahora se hace tanto ruido con ese pueblo: le tengo una manía...*
>
> Antonio Gala, "Los buenos días perdidos", 1972 (España).

En este último caso se nota que la intención del autor es la de "hubo que hacer de todo", que es el significado que se le da a la expresión "hacer a pluma y a pelo" (con los términos cambiados).

La expresión inversa tiene un significado similar:

> *El hecho es que se llama así, y que en el pueblo que se desparrama a corta distancia de él, le consideran como su puerto de mar los contados labradores que hacen a pluma y a pelo; quiero decir, que así manejan el dalle y tumban un prado en agosto, como cinglan en la chalana y calan la sereña o tienden las redes o arrastran el retuelle por la canal casi enjuta.*
>
> José María de Pereda, "La puchera", 1889 (España).

Nuevamente la expresión se usa como "hacer de todo". Esta expresión es más antigua y está en el diccionario desde 1925, ya que a pesar de que aparece en diccionarios anteriores, antes de este año su significado no era el actual, sino este otro:

> No desperdiciar nada, aceptando cualquier cosa, aunque no sea tan buena como él quisiera.

El viraje de la expresión "hacer a pelo y pluma" (en ese orden) hacia la bisexualidad se puede encontrar en textos más recientes:

> *Él no es que fuera lo que se dice mariquita, porque hacer hacía a pelo y a pluma, dado el caso [...].*
>
> José Luis Martín Vigil, "En defensa propia", 1985 (España).

Así pues, si bien es cierto que el orden puede alterar el significado de la expresión, no se debe perder de vista que el orden "pelo y pluma" se ha usado hasta hace muy poco con el mismo sentido que "pluma y pelo". En todo caso, te pongo como ejemplo la expresión que he citado antes: si yo te digo que me da igual la carne que el pescado puedes pensar que soy bisexual, pero si te digo que me da igual el pescado que la carne puedes pensar que he alterado el orden de la expresión para hacer énfasis en que hablo en sentido literal y no figurado. Puede que eso pasara con la expresión: "hacer a pluma y a pelo" existía ya en el siglo XIX, pero "a pelo y a pluma" es ya del siglo XX, y posiblemente ese cambio de orden de los términos fue el que condujo a su sentido figurado.

Comment: @walen sabía que la segunda parte de esa cita iba a sorprender a más de uno... :-D ¡Todos al DLE a buscar términos!

Comment: Yo también me he queadado un poco así: O_O. No conozco la mitad de las palabras a partir de la última coma

Comment: "A pluma y a pelo" aparece en el Diccionario de Autoridades, por lo que es anterior al siglo XIX